# Ionic2 - Transparent navigation bar and custom icon

Tags: ionic2

I need to do a transparent navigation bar and replace the default icon (Back) in Ionic 2.

Answer (score 1):

you should try [Ionic Configurations](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/config/Config/) will help you in setting back Icon in whole application.

Comment: Ok. I am trying with this code in app.module.ts:
  imports: [
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp, {
      backButtonIcon: 'assets/icon/atras.png'
    }, {}
  )
  ],

Doesn't work.